# Get correct child class instance no switch case

Tags: java, oop, optimization, switch-statement, polymorphism

I am trying to make a small calculator app and learning OOPS concepts. I watched [this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4F72VULWFvc).
It shows how polymorphism can be used to avoid switch statements.

I have 4 operator buttons in my app (`+`, `-`, `/`, `*`). I am using 2 stacks for operators and operands
When user taps on any button operand or operator, I try to create a infix tree for the current expression and keep operator in operator stack. 
When user hits "calculate" I go through the operator stack and adjust the infix tree based on operator precedence.

I have abstract `Node` class, `ValueNode` -> `Node`, abstract operatorNode, AddNode -> operatorNode, `SubtractNode` -> `OperatorNode` and so on.

My code is inspired from following link in case the above description is not clear. 
http://cplusplus.kurttest.com/notes/stack.html#binary-expression-tree

My problem is, how do I create correct child class object based on the operator char from stack without using switch?

So, given char (`+` or `-` or `*` or `/`) how do I create `AddNode` or `SubtractNode` without using switch.

Comment: Instead of describing your code, post it. It will be easier to understand and help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a map from operator to a factory that creates the correct instance. This way you:
1. avoid a switch
2. avoid having to update the tree creation when you add new operands, just register them in the map

Whatever is not in the map can be assumed to be an operand (constant or  variable)

Comment: gracias my friend.